# web maps - hover/click/tap mobile freindliness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, responsive-design, maps, leaflet

So I am making a web map app with leaflet/rails and since I am the only developer I am going to just do a responsive design instead of making an entirely new mobile app. I am having trouble figuring out what the most friendly ui is for desktop and mobile.

Right now I am doing something similar to foursquare as shown here, https://foursquare.com/explore?mode=url&near=Minneapolis&q=tacos.

So when you hover it pops up, then when you click the marker it stays open. Foursquare has an entirely separate mobile app though and it's clear from their site that you aren't supposed to use it for mobile. I want to know though if this configuration is mobile friendly, so if a user clicks the marker it will simply just stay open and the hover effect will not do anything.

Is this a good way to go about it or is there an accepted way to do mobile marker events?

I am new to web maps, especially making them responsive/mobile friendly so any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share what I've found so far. When on mobile hover basically goes away and click is replaced with tap. Hover still sometimes come in when the user does an abnormal slight click.